# One way javascript communication

Tags: elm

I want to write a `Cmd` that causes some javascript to run but never has a value that comes back into the system.

something like:

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        AlertTime ->
          (model, alertTime)
```

Notice that `alertTime` would generate a `Cmd` that called some javascript function to alert the user of the current time, but I don't need anything to come back into the elm runtime.  I'm not trying to solve this exact problem of generating an alert of the current time, it's just to illustrate the problem I'm trying to solve.

How do I facilitate 1 way communication out to javascript in accordance with elm architecture? I could write a native module that did this on a function call but I feel that's skirting the elm architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is `ports`. Declare your module to be a `port module` (that is, replace the word `module` at the top of your file with `port module`), and declare an outgoing port:

```
port alert : String -> Cmd msg
```

This defines an Elm function `alert` which takes a `String` and produces a command. (Note that it is a `Cmd msg`, lowercase `msg`, meaning that it doesn't actually ever result in a capital-M `Msg`; the fact that `msg` is lowercase indicates that it is a type variable, and `alert "blah"` will be returnable from *any* update function, no matter the concrete `Msg` type.)

In JavaScript, you'd write something like this:

```
app.ports.alert.subscribe(function(str) {
    alert(str);
});
```

That code "subscribes" to messages being sent by the Elm code to the `alert` port -- don't confuse this with Elm `subscriptions`, which listen for messages being sent *to* Elm.

Now, in Elm, you can create commands like `alert "Hi there"`. When executed, that command will call the function you defined in Javascript, causing an alert to appear with the text `"Hi there"`.

Note that you cannot declare, e.g., `alertTime : Cmd msg` with no arguments. You *can* declare `alertTime : () -> Cmd msg`, and use it by returning `alertTime ()` from your update function. I believe this will send Javascript the value `[]`, if your Javascript function accepts input.

Comment: Ah so it has to take an argument. I kept getting the error that my type sig was incorrect as `alertTime : Platform.Cmd.Cmd x` and I was like "nah, that's what I want". Cool, so now I have to: `doAlertTime : String -> Cmd x` and `alertTime = doAlertTime ""`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach it to an event (e.g. `onClick`), you could (ab)use the `attribute` function like this:

```
view model =
    input [type_ "button", attribute "onClick" "javascript:your_function()" ] []
```

`elm` won't parse the return value, which is fine in your case